# Odd NEST client issue in unit tests

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a client I'm instantiating in a controller:

```
    public ElasticConnector()
    {
        var node = new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}:{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticHost"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticPort"]));

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
            node
        ).ExposeRawResponse();

        Client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    }
```

Which works fine and I can make queries, however when instantiating the same class in a unit test and I run the same controller the client keeps returning:

```
 operation has timed out
```

Unit Test(MSpec):

```
 public class SearchControllerSpec
    {
        public class setup_controller
        {
            public static SearchController controller;

            public static IHttpActionResult results;

            Establish context = () =>
            {
                var client = new ElasticConnector();
                //ElasticTestInstance.SetupTestInstance(client);

                controller = new SearchController(client);
            };
        }

        public class when_searching_with_a_hyphenated_term : setup_controller
        {
            Because of = () => results = controller.GetResults("anti-emetic");

            It should_return_OK = () => results.ShouldBeOfExactType<OkNegotiatedContentResult<string>>();

}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: May you post the unit test?

Comment: @Rob Sorry, I should have included that, thanks for asking so politely! :-)